# How to convert maven surefire into gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-surefire-plugin

**Before migration**
I can set -Darguments in mvn test -D.... build was started with surefire but in Gradle I can't do it

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/RunCucumberIT.java</include>
                    <release>11</release>
                </includes>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>${parallel.count}</threadCount>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -Xmx2048m
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

**After migration**

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0'
    }

    test {
        ignoreFailures = true
        include '**/RunCucumberIT.java'
//option doesn't works
        //options {
            //parallel = "methods"
            //forkCount = 4
        }
    }
```

I need to run it in parallel, and also **-Darguments=someArgument** doesn't work

Comment: Have the same issue, did u find any solution for this migration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the system property in your Gradle task.

example:

```
task <task_name> {
  systemProperty "arguments", System.getProperty("arguments")
}
```

Now the application can read -Darguments=someArgument